# What's the equivalent to objcopy on macOS?

Tags: osx, gnu, binary, bsd

I would expect `llvm-objcopy` to be installed on macOS, since its counterpart `llvm-objdump` is installed toghether with other LLVM tools like `clang`.

What is the `llvm-objcopy`-equivalent tool to use on macOS?

Comment: OT note - 41 minutes after writing this is the first google hit for llvm-objcopy

Comment: @Mark, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: When installing clang with `brew`, the `llvm-objcopy` is available on macOS. Or could you please rephrase the question?

Comment: Since objcopy is such an important tool, I'd guess Apple would ship it or something equivalent with macOS, they don't?

Comment: @antonone, is it possible to only install llvm-objcopy? If so, how?

Comment: @Shuzheng, do you require exactly `llvm-objcopy`? Because if you require only a objcopy-style tool, you can install `brew install binutils` to get `gobjcopy`, the GNU version of objcopy tool which supports `mach-o-x86-64` format. But if you want `llvm-objcopy` in this particular version, then I'm not sure if you can install it  without the whole llvm. As for importance; it's subjective, important things for Apple aren't always the same things as for developers unfortunately ;(

Comment: @antonone, I just need a tool that lets me edit binaries from the command line. So, is gobjcopy the best alternative? I see that Brew's LLVM is version 7, which is kinda outdated?

Comment: @Shuzheng, it depends on what edits you want to perform. For my use cases, `gobjcopy` did everything I wanted to do. Is it the best? I have no idea. There's also Agner Fog's `objconv`.

Comment: @antonone, I have installed `llvm-objcopy`. However, I cannot manipulate Mach-O object files through ` --input-target, --output-target`, since Mach-O is not mentioned as a supported file format here: https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-objcopy.html#supported-formats - Any ideas??